# Необходимо подсчитать и удалить символы ":" в строке С++

Tags: c++, строки

Дан массив символов. Удалить символ «двоеточие» (:) и подсчитать количество удаленных символов.
Вот что у меня вышло но программа не работает, посчитать количество символов вышло а удалить их нет.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    string str = "sdgdsfg:fsdgf:sgdsdb:afewfv:awrm cs";
    cout << str << endl;
    int n = count(str.begin(), str.end(), ':');
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) str.erase(':');//Проблема в этой строке
    cout << n << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Потому что erase принимает итератор. Ты можешь воспользоваться алгоритмом std::find

Comment: @Lofectr, если вы имеете ввиду std::string::erase, то он не только итератор принимает(см. ответ Harry), и лучше(проще) воспользоваться функцией_членом, чем обобщенным алгоритмом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тогда уж сделайте так:

```
int n = count(str.begin(), str.end(), ':');
size_t pos;
while((pos = str.find(':')) != str.npos) str.erase(pos,1);
cout << n << endl;
```

А то вы все стараетесь удалять символ в позиции с номером, равным ASCII-коду `;`.

Comment: Тогда уж 
int n = 0;;
size_t pos;
while((pos = str.find(':')) != str.npos) {str.erase(pos,1); ++n; }

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Конечно, лучше так. Но ваш способ - который в вашем ответе - еще лучше. Хотя асимптотика везде одинакова...

Comment: адресовано  читателям( думаю не помешает)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предпочел вариант перемещения в конец и одной операции удаления:

```
auto A = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ':'),
    B = str.end();    
str.erase( A, B);
cout << str << '\n' << B - A;
```